# Label gets misaligned when size of MUI select is set to small

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When the size is normal, the label is positioned properly but when it's changed to small, the label is pushed to the bottom of the field.How can I position the label at the center of the field? The initial value of key is set to an empty string.

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="key-label">Key</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="key-label"
    id="key"
    value={key}
    label="Key"
    onChange={handleChange}
    size="small"
  >
    <MenuItem value={"A"}>A</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"B"}>B</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"C"}>C</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

[image: Small size]

[image: Normal size]

Comment: None of the answer works when Select is multiple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to replace the `Select` with a `TextField` element with an attribute `select`. I also got rid of the `InputLabel` and the related attribute of `labelId`. It looks great now.

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <TextField
    select
    id="key"
    value={key}
    label="Key"
    onChange={handleChange}
    required
    size="small"
  >
    <MenuItem value={"A"}>A</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"B"}>B</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"C"}>C</MenuItem>
  </TextField>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 12):

This is not a bug. You need to apply `size="small"` to `<FormControl>` too.

```js
<FormControl fullWidth size="small">
  <InputLabel id="key">Label</InputLabel>
  <Select
    id="key"
    value={key}
    label="Key"
    onChange={handleChange}
    required
    size="small">
    <MenuItem value={"A"}>A</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"B"}>B</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"C"}>C</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use like this,

In the `InputLabel` you have to set size="small"

```
<FormControl fullWidth size="small" >
 <InputLabel size="small" id="role">Role</InputLabel>
    <Select
       labelId="role"
       id="role"
       name="role"
       label="Role"
       size="small"
    />
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Work for me. In case Select. Thanks